# Winphone 8 GPS weirdness

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-mobile-gps

I'm writing a POC for WinPhone 8 (I have a Nokia 928 running the 8.1 release).

One of the features I'm working with is GeoLocator and I'm noticing some odd behavior.  My app gets your current location and then tracks your movement and calculates the distance between the two points.  The odd behavior is that I'm sitting still and the PositionChanged event is firing!  What gives?  I've yet to move and my app already says the distance from the origin and my current location is ~9Meters.

Is this normal behavior for GPS?  If so, what is the recommended method of dealing with it?

Here is how my GeoLocator is setup:

```
            _Geolocator = new Geolocator();
            _Geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
            _Geolocator.MovementThreshold = 5;
            _Geolocator.ReportInterval = 1000;
```

I have a button that gets the current location and starts the position changed event (chopping code for brevity):

```
        Geoposition position = await _Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

        _trackLocation = true;
        _currentLocation = position;
        OrigLongitude = _currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude;
        OrigLatitude = _currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude;

        _Geolocator.PositionChanged += _Geolocator_PositionChanged;
        Message = "tracking location";
```

and the PositionChanged event:

```
            _currentLocation = args.Position; 

            //calculate the distance
            double d = _pointTracker.DistanceTo(_currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude, _currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude);
            double accuracy = _currentLocation.Coordinate.Accuracy;
            if (true == show.Contains("tracking X"))
            {
                show = "tracking Y " + accuracy.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                show = "tracking X " + accuracy.ToString();
            }

            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => { Distance = d; }); 
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => { Message = show; });
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => { Longitude = _currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude; });
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => { Latitude =    _currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude; });
```

The show junk just lets me see that a message showing that the event is firing.  the only thing of interest in it is the GPS accuracy I'm getting back (usually it's about 3 meters, in doors it is 9 meters).

Any direction or help would be greatly appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Increase the movement threshold. 5 meters is very low. Make it at least 10.

Comment: That's pretty normal for a consumer grade GPS, especially indoors.

Comment: What kind of places have you tested your app in?

Comment: Mostly outside my house.  One of the tests I did was to put the phone on the ground and just sit watching the display and the lat & long would occasionally change.  I even kicked the threshold up to 20meters and it still happens.

Comment: I've looke at a few solutions and I think I'm going to change the approach: I won't use the PositionChanged event any longer.  Instead I'm going to setup a time that grabs a set of reading and then averages them.  We'll see if that works any better.